# Powershell giving an error when hiding rows from a DataGridView

Tags: powershell, datagridview, rows, visibility, selected

My powershell code to hide the unselected rows is working fine except for an issue when I decide to deselect a row from my current selection, which is meant to be highlighted, before to hide everything else.
In this case I get the following error:

```
Exception setting "Visible": "Row associated with the currency manager's position cannot be made invisible."
```

If a new selection is done by clicking row by row with Ctrl key down and only adding new rows to the selection, there is no error. But once you deselect one or more rows from an existing selection before to run the hiding Function, the last deselected row is not hidden and the Powershell returns the mentioned error.

The code which changes the visibility for all non-selected rows:

```
foreach($row in $DataGridView1.Rows){
            if (!$DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Contains($row)){
                $row.Visible = $false
            }
```

After some research I found some information about `SuspendBinding`, `ResumeBinding` and `CurrentCell = $null` but it seems not to be a solution for this particular problem.

Even using those methods, I'm still getting the same error.

The main idea is to hide everything except the selected rows when a checkbox is checked, and keeping the selection active all the time, without losing it after the hide-unhide process.

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

**xmlfile.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <fruitList>
      <fruit>
          <variety>./banana.zip</variety>
          <name>banana - the yellow one</name>
          <image>./images/banana-image.png</image>
          <weight>0.8</weight>
      </fruit>
      <fruit>
          <variety>./orange.zip</variety>
          <name>orange - the orange one</name>
          <image>./images/orange-image.png</image>
          <weight>0.7</weight>
      </fruit>
      <fruit>
          <variety>./lemon.zip</variety>
          <name>lemon - the green one</name>
          <image>./images/lemon-image.png</image>
          <weight>0.5</weight>
      </fruit>
      <fruit>
          <variety>./apple.zip</variety>
          <name>apple - the red one</name>
          <image>./images/apple-image.png</image>
          <weight>0.9</weight>
      </fruit>
            <fruit>
          <variety>./pineaple.zip</variety>
          <name>pineaple - the pineaple one</name>
          <image>./images/pineaple-image.png</image>
          <weight>1.5</weight>
       </fruit>
  </fruitList>
```

**POWERSHELL CODE:**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

#region begin GUI{ 

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '800,800'
$Form.text                       = "Gamelist Editor"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false

$DataGridView1                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$DataGridView1.BackColor         = "#f7f7f7"
$DataGridView1.width             = 770
$DataGridView1.height            = 570
$DataGridView1.Anchor            = 'top,bottom,left,right'
$DataGridView1.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,168)

$CheckBox1                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$CheckBox1.text                  = "Show only selected"
$CheckBox1.AutoSize              = $false
$CheckBox1.width                 = 157
$CheckBox1.height                = 20
$CheckBox1.Anchor                = 'bottom,left'
$CheckBox1.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,765)
$CheckBox1.Font                  = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Label1                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.text                     = "no selection"
$Label1.AutoSize                 = $true
$Label1.width                    = 25
$Label1.height                   = 10
$Label1.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(250,765)
$Label1.Font                     = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$Label1.Anchor                   = 'bottom,left'

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($DataGridView1,$CheckBox1,$Label1))

#region gui events {

$DataGridView1.Add_CellMouseDown({ buffer_SelectedRows })
$DataGridView1.Add_Sorted({ Load_Buffer })
$DataGridView1.Add_MouseClick({ countSelection })
$CheckBox1.Add_CheckedChanged({ hideSelected })
#endregion events }

#endregion GUI }

$DataGridView1.ReadOnly = $true
$DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = $false
$DataGridView1.SelectionMode = 'FullRowSelect'
$DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 16
Function importXML(){
    $xml_input = "xmlfile.xml"
    $ds = New-Object System.Data.Dataset
    $ds.ReadXml($xml_input)
    $DataGridView1.DataSource = $ds.Tables[0]
    $DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
    $DataGridView1.CurrentCell = $null
}
importXML
Function buffer_SelectedRows(){
    $global:buffer = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
    foreach($row in $DataGridView1.SelectedRows){
    $buffer.Add($row.Cells[0].Value)
    }
}
Function Load_Buffer(){
    $DataGridView1.CurrentCell = $null
    $DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
    $rowIndex = -1
    foreach($row in $DataGridView1.Rows){
        foreach($i in $buffer){
            if($row.Cells[0].Value -eq $i)
            {
            $rowIndex = $row.Index
            $DataGridView1.Rows[$rowIndex].Selected = $true
            }
        }
    }
    $Label1.Text = ($DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count.ToString()) + " selected"
}
Function hideSelected(){
    if ($CheckBox1.Checked){
        $DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = $false
        $DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = $false
        foreach ($row in $DataGridView1.Rows){
            if (!$DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Contains($row)){
                $DataGridView1.DataSource.SuspendBinding
                $row.Visible = $false
                $DataGridView1.DataSource.ResumeBinding
            }
        }
        foreach($row in $DataGridView1.SelectedRows){
            $buffer.Add($row.Cells[0].Value)
        }
    } else {
        $DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = $true
        $DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = $true
        foreach($row in $DataGridView1.Rows){
            $DataGridView1.CurrentCell = $null
            $row.Visible = $true
        }
        Load_Buffer
    }
}
Function countSelection(){
    $Label1.Text = ($DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count.ToString()) + " selected"
}
[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Anyway you can knock your question down to a few lines? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Adam, which part of my code/ question is unnecessary? The problem is referring to a GUI, so we need to see a DataGridView and all the code related to it.
Can you help me to reduce the code in a few lines and keeping a GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Just before the foreach where it sets Visible=$False, setting the currentcell to null should work. The error went away for me:

```
$DataGridView1.CurrentCell = $null
foreach ($row in $DataGridView1.Rows){
  if (!$DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Contains($row)){
            $DataGridView1.DataSource.SuspendBinding
            $row.Visible = $false
            $DataGridView1.DataSource.ResumeBinding
   }
 }
```

Or if you want to select the last row:

```
$DataGridView1.CurrentCell = $DataGridView1.rows[$DataGridView1.RowCount-1].Cells[0]
```